# Make own macros precede libraries macros in c++

Tags: c++, macros

I have something like this in header.h:

```
#ifdef SOME_MACRO
#define MACRO_A
    //Some code 1
#else
#define MACRO_A
    //Some code 2
#endif
```

In main.cpp:

```
#include "header.h"
#define SOME_MACRO
...
MACRO_A; //It should be Some code 1
```

Is there a way to make `SOME_MACRO` definition in `main.cpp` affect `header.h`?

Putting `#define SOME_MACRO` before the header doesn't make changes.

Comment: _"Putting #define SOME_MACRO before the header doesn't make changes."_ It definitely should. Show how you defined `MACRO_A` in reality please.

Comment: See [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d62dc1f782f69f38).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, yes you have to put the definition of your selector before the include statement:

```
#define SOME_MACRO  // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
#include "header.h"
```

Second, if I take your sample literally, you probably missed that all code in a macro definition needs to go in a single line:

```
#ifdef SOME_MACRO
// Note the escaped line endings below: \
#define MACRO_A \
    //Some code 1
#else
#define MACRO_A \
    //Some code 2
#endif
```